# setOnMenuItemClickListener executes only once

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, navigationview

```
  invite.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        mainViewModel.executeInvite(
            InviteBody(
                Constants.apiKey,
                Constants.apiPass,
                Constants.apiInviteService
            )
        )
        true
    }
```

Since the function   **mainViewModel.executeInvite** being called, the listener only executes once.

The executeInvite is a function in the below that uses coroutines:

```
fun executeInvite(inviteBody: InviteBody) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
```

If I remove this piece of code, everything works perfectly.

The invite is an item in the side menu that generates a dynamic link from the backend on click.

Comment: Try to play with the returnable by listener result (you return here "true").
I don't quite understand how it works, but it affects the behavior.

Comment: tried false and it also didn't work

Comment: Maybe are you using Moxy and it related with its Commands strategy?

Comment: @kirkadev I am using MVVM but that wasn't it. Solved the issue by doing a DialogFragment Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for everyone suffering from this

I managed to solve this issue by creating a DialogFragment and calling it from menu click listener. Code below:

```
 invite.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        InviteDialogFragment().show(
            supportFragmentManager, Constants.apiInviteService)
        true
    }
```

Had another viewmodel inside the Invite Fragment which would call the API and observe the result over there. For some reason, calling an API from onMenuCLickListener was causing an exception at the level of the view, making all the other items of the nav items unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove this piece of code, everything works perfectly.

So you're telling me that if you put

```kotlin
invite.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    Log.d("asdf", "hello")
    true
}
```

in `executeInvite`, then press the menu item for invite 3 times, that you'd see 3 log statements saying "hello" ? If so, then your listener should be correct and the error is happening somewhere in the code that `executeInvite` is doing.

If that is the case, you can debug that by doing something like this:

```kotlin
fun executeInvite(inviteBody: InviteBody) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        runCatching { /* whatever code you're doing */ }
            .onSuccess { Log.d("asdf", "successful!") }
            .onFailure { throwable -> Log.d("asdf", "failure!", throwable) }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first point is correct, but I am not receiving any error in the second part, and I have already surrounded it by try catch

Comment: `runCatching` is how you do a try/catch for coroutines. try that and confirm that it is successful. If the first point is correct (about the logs) then we know the listener works and the issue is somewhere inside the `executeInvite` (or at least the issue is as a _result_ of `executeInvite` and is breaking the listener)

Comment: I already did. Thank you so much. I posted an answere. The thing is I tried different APIs , I even tried calling it from coroutine scopes. This was the exception causing it: /ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent(). Anyway solved it by doing a DialogFragment and executing the API there. Thanks

Comment: also one more thing forgot to mention is that even if I call vm to post a value without an API call , it would cause the listener to freeze.